# Not able to start IBM MQ explorer getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting error while opening IBM MQ explorer. It was working fine before but suddenly stopped working and I don't understand the error can you guys please help?

When opened is says `Error creating the view.`

Below is the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:66)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:127)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.tests.Notify.pluginEnabled(Notify.java:96)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.base.NotificationManager.notifyPluginEnabled(NotificationManager.java:869)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.base.UiPlugin.sendPluginEnablementEvents(UiPlugin.java:2483)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.base.UiPlugin.addNavigatorView(UiPlugin.java:1574)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.internal.views.MQNavigatorView.createPartControl(MQNavigatorView.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActivationList.setActive(WorkbenchPage.java:4080)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$17.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3145)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3659)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3296)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$25.runWithException(Workbench.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3659)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3296)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.internal.base.RcpApplication.run(RcpApplication.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethod(EclipseAppContainer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1148)
```

Comment: Please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What has changed?

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before and not working now, as Morag suggests, indicates something has changed.

A `NoClassDefFoundError` error would indicate that your Java class path no longer points to a needed .class / .jar file.

Your error stack suggests that you are using MQ Explorer on Eclipse to connect to a MQ server. You are not finding an Eclipse class - `org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription`, which indicates that your Eclipse environment has become corrupted. Did you upgrade Eclipse, or Java on your machine?

IMHO your title is misleading, as it should read "unable to start MQ Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

The errors which you have pasted look like that its the MQ explorer which has gone for a toss and not the MQ server as such. Try using the command line commands to handle your MQ. If things look ok there, then its for sure to do with some missing jars from your libraries. Also try to recall if you have changed anything in the recent past.